# Count different consecutive rows according group by a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to sum the number of different consecutive rows for each customer.

So my data looks like this dummy one:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A', 'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
                   'Time':['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00', '05:00','06:00','07:00','00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00','05:00','06:00','07:00'],
                   'Lat':[20,20,30,30,30,40,20,20,20,20,30,30,30, 40,20,20], 
                   'Lon':[40,40,50,50,50,60,40,40,40,40,50,50,50,60,40,40]})


     Customer    Time    Lat  Lon
0      A         00:00   20   40
1      A         01:00   20   40
2      A         02:00   30   50 
3      A         03:00   30   50
4      A         04:00   30   50
5      A         05:00   40   60
6      A         06:00   20   40
7      A         07:00   20   40
8      B         00:00   20   40
9      B         01:00   20   40
10     B         02:00   30   50
11     B         03:00   30   50
12     B         04:00   30   50
13     B         05:00   40   60
14     B         06:00   20   40
15     B         07:00   20   40
```

And I want to count the number of different rows (according to both Lat and Lon) by customer that aren't consecutive. So, in the example it would return 4 for both customers even though there are only 3 different pairs of Lat and Lon.

This:

```
test = (df['Lat'] != df['Lat'].shift(1)).values.sum()
```

Takes care of only one column and doesn't group by Customer.

But I can't seem to do

```
df[['Lat','Lon']] != df[['Lat','Lon']]
```

it gives:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

or group by Customer. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using `shift` create a new key , then with `drop_duplicates`

```
df['key']=df.groupby('Customer').apply(lambda x : x[['Lat','Lon']].ne(x[['Lat','Lon']].shift()).all(1).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df.drop_duplicates(['Customer','key'])
   Customer   Time  Lat  Lon  key
0         A  00:00   20   40    1
2         A  02:00   30   50    2
5         A  05:00   40   60    3
6         A  06:00   20   40    4
8         B  00:00   20   40    1
10        B  02:00   30   50    2
13        B  05:00   40   60    3
14        B  06:00   20   40    4
```

Comment: @adhg `all` means all the row equal to True

Comment: got it @WeNYoBen

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

```
df.groupby('Customer')[['Lat', 'Lon']].apply(lambda s: s.diff().ne(0).all(1).sum())

Customer
A    4
B    4
dtype: int64
```